# how can I collapse multiple lines into one line with the m4 preprocessor?

Tags: m4

We have an internal configuration file that processes lines one by one.  Unfortunately, the lines have gotten really big over time.  The config processor does an m4 pre-process on the config file.  Is there a way for me to collapse multiple (readable) lines into one line using m4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved with this question:

[in m4's patsubst, how do I replace newlines with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567668/in-m4s-patsubst-how-do-i-replace-newlines-with-spaces)