# in m4's patsubst, how do I replace newlines with spaces?

Tags: regex, makefile, preprocessor, m4

How can I tell m4's `patsubstr` to replace all newlines in a string with a space?

I've tried:

```
patsubst(MULTI_LINE_STR_DEFINE,`\n',` ')
```

and

```
patsubst(MULTI_LINE_STR_DEFINE,`\\n',` ')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
patsubst(MULTI_LINE_STR_DEFINE,`
',` ')
```

That is, you put the newline, literally, between quotes.