# How to match newlines in GNU M4 _properly_

Tags: newline, m4

I am trying to craft a macro replacing newlines.

My first try was:

```
    define(`m4_pascal_str',`
     patsubst(`$1',`^\(.*\)$',`\1++')
')

m4_pascal_str(`

11

22 33 44
')

define(zz,`

11

22 33 44
')
m4_pascal_str(`zz')
```

That gives correct answer when not using intermediate macro, and match only last newline otherwise. See results below:

```
 ++

++
11++
++
22 33 44++

++

11

22 33 44
++
```

Then I found similar question:
[in m4's patsubst, how do I replace newlines with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567668/in-m4s-patsubst-how-do-i-replace-newlines-with-spaces)

So, I just made:

```
define(`m4_pascal_str',`
     patsubst(`$1',`
',`++')
')

m4_pascal_str(`

11

22 33 44
')

define(zz,`

11

22 33 44
')
m4_pascal_str(`zz')
```

It gives:

```
 ++++11++++22 33 44++

11

22 33 44
```

The last alternative suffers the same problem.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last line try removing the quoting around the **zz**. When I did this I got the same result for both m4_pascal_str calls:

```
     ++
++
11++
++
22 33 44++
++




     ++
++
11++
++
22 33 44++
++
```